# What is the meaning of Book of Boba Fett’s Episode 1 title, “Stranger in a Strange Land?”

Tags: star-wars, symbols, the-book-of-boba-fett

*The Book of Boba Fett* Episode 1 is titled, “Stranger in a Strange Land.”

Sci-fi aficionados understand an association to Heinlein’s 1961 novel of that same title. The same people also understand the phrase originated in the King James Bible with the *Book of Exodus 2:22*:

> And she bare him a son, and he called his name Gershom: for he said, I have been a stranger in a strange land.

Is the episode title intended to allegorically associate Boba Fett with Moses, or to Valentine Michael Smith?

What is the intent for titling this for *Book of Boba Fett’s* first episode?

Comment: don't overthink it - more likely just to him being a 'stranger' to the sand people, then being accepted

Comment: Shouldn’t it be “_The Boba of Fett_”? Why is it a book when there’s no book 

Comment: Interestingly enough, Gershom comes from the Hebrew predicate גר שם (gar sham), which literally means "live over there".

Answer (score 1):

### The Going Big Answer (or Keep Digging When You Hit Rock Bottom): The Title intends to allegorically connect Boba Fett with Moses

Yes, I can be accused of overthinking this: Yes, I’ll argue Boba Fett *is* Moses.

After two episodes, it is becoming clear Boba Fett has come to bring order to the chaos of the void left behind by the death of Jabba the Hutt. In this sense, Boba Fett has been delivered to criminal underworld to bring them the law, and set them on the right path.

Since Jabba’s fall, the underworld has been unrestrained; some could say lost its way, becoming prone to excess, and generally engaging in behaviors that are putting its criminal soul at risk.

More than just finding himself a man out of his element, *The Book of Boba Fett* is showing us that Fett is no longer the ruthless hunter we saw in ESB or the hemchman of RotJ; he is a profoundly changed man in the wake of his Sarlacc ordeal, and seeks to bring his profound vision of a new way to Tatooine’s criminal underworld.

This take is not so much lunacy as it sounds, as Episode 2 shows a focused attention on moral aspects of the conduct of criminality. Speaking with Garsa Fwip, Boba Fett believes the Hutt twins will be too preoccupied with:

> the "debauchery of Hutta" to bother him on Tatooine.

The compassion he showed to the Gamorrean guards has paid off, and will continue to pay off for Fett in his emerging criminal empire. No longer is he known for disintegrating first, and asking questions later, Fett brings a new message for reigning over one’s criminal empire.

Upon his return, Fett is showing himself to offer a more compassionate, more orderly, more professional pathway forward from the current *debauchery*, or “lawlessness” of the Tatooine underworld.

In this regard, he is like Moses, refocusing the Jews after their exodus, on the Law.